# Flask-Restplus how to combine data from 2 table into single data response?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-restplus

I am using Flask-Restplus and SQLAlchemy to develop my API. I want to return a response with information from two SQAlchemy objects, a user and a device, with a 1:1 relationship between them.

I have a query that looks like this:

```
details = db.session.query(User, Device).filter(User.id == Device.id) \
                    .filter(User.email== data['email'])\
                    .all()
```

For now, the result of the query above can be printed in console is like this:

```
[(<User 'None'>, <Device 1>)]
```

I want my API endpoint to return the following JSON:

```js
{
  "data": [
    [
      {
        "id": 20,
        "name": null,
        "token": "Some String here"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Here is my DTO:

```
class UserDto:
    # this is for input
    user = api.model('user', {
        'email': fields.String(required=False, description='phone number'),
        'name': fields.String(required=False, description='username'),
        'device_id': fields.String(required=False,description='user_device_id'),
   })

   # this is for output
    details = api.model('details', {
        'id': fields.Integer(required=False, description='the id'),
        'name': fields.String(required=False, description='name'),
        'token': fields.String(required=False, description='token')
    })
```

Models for `User` and `Device`:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users_info"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String)
    device = db.relationship('Device', backref='user')
    # .. more fields ..


class Device(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user_device"

    user_device_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    token = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    # .. more fields ..
```

I order to achieve JSON result above, I want the `id` and `name` is from the `User` object, and `token` is from the `Device` object.

Controller:

```
api = UserDto.api
_user = UserDto.user
_details = UserDto.details

@api.route('/')
class User(Resource):
    @api.response(201, 'successful')
    @api.expect(_user, validate=True)
    @api.marshal_list_with(_details, envelope='data')
    def post(self):
        data = request.json
        return user(data=data)
```

Actual Response:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      {
        "id": 20,
        "name": null,
        "token": null
      },
      {
        "id": 20,
        "name": null,
        "token": "some string here"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

As you can see here, the same record appears 2 twice (once with `token` being `null` and once with `token` with the string I want).

How can I achieve the response that I want above?

Comment: This is still lacking in clarity. What data is in the response, *just* the user device details? So `20` is the `id` for the `Device` object? That model doesn't *have* a `id` field, only your Restplus model has that field. You can [rename attributes](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshalling.html#renaming-attributes) but currently your examples *can't actually work*.

Comment: Can you show us what attributes from what objects need to be reflected in the API? I did my best editing your question, but as it stands it is not clear if you want data from both objects or just the user device.

Comment: `id` and `name` is from `user` object..and `token` is from `user_details` object

Comment: bro I edited the question..let me know what u need again

Comment: Is the `User.email` column perhaps meant to be `unique=True`? Can multiple users exist with the same email address?

Comment: one  email only can use by 1 user

Comment: Then your response shouldn't really be a list, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get two output entries because you have two objects (rows) in your query. You don't need to add the `Device` object to your query, because it is already available as the `user.device`. Adjust your Restplus model to use `user.device.token` attribute.

So you need to alter your query to only load the user:

```
return User.query.filter_by(email == data['email']).all()
```

If the `User.email` field is supposed to be unique (an email address should really reference just one user in your database), consider using `.first()` instead of `.all()`, then wrapping the return value of `.first()` in a list, or more logical, changing your return value into a single JSON object without a list. Also consider using the [`first_or_404()` method](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/queries/#queries-in-views) to automatically produce a `404 Not Found` response in case there is no user with this email.

You then need to configure your `details` API model:

```
details = api.model('details', {
    'id': fields.Integer(required=False, description='the id'),
    'name': fields.String(required=False, description='name'),
    'token': fields.String(
        attribute='device.token',
        required=False,
        description='token'
    )
})
```

Note the `attribute` field for `token`, we are telling Flask-Restplus here to take the `token` attribute of the `device` attribute of each object.

This does require you to alter your SQLAlchemy model, because you don't have a one-on-one relationship defined right now. You have a [one to many](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many), so `user.device` is actually a list. Add [`uselist=False`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.uselist) to your `device` relationship:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users_info"

    # ...
    device = db.relationship('Device', backref='user', uselist=False)
```

That restricts you to a *scalar* value, so a single `device` object per user.

Or, if you did mean for it to be a one-to-many relationship, then you'll have to replace the `token` field with a `tokens` *list*:

```
details = api.model('details', {
    'id': fields.Integer(required=False, description='the id'),
    'name': fields.String(required=False, description='name'),
    'token': fields.List(
        fields.String(attribute='token', required=False),
        description='array of tokens for all user devices',
        attribute='device'
    )
})
```

You may want to rename `device` to `devices` in that case, to better reflect that you have multiple.

Note that in all cases, you'll want to think about [loading strategies](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html). If you are always going to access the device associated with the user, adding `lazy="joined"` to the `device` relationship is going to help performance. Alternatively, add `.options(db.joinedload('device'))` to your `User` query, before the `.first()` or `.all()` call:

```
return User.query.filter_by(email == data['email']).options(db.joinedload('device')).all()
```

Comment: bro I modify the API model as u state,but the token is still null even though it exist in my table

Comment: at the same time,I modify the query as u stated

Comment: @ken: I see now you filtered on `Device` with `User.id == Device.id`. That's not your foreign key, so that's the wrong `Device` object you have there, the correct foreign key relationship is `User.id == Device.user_id`. For my query as `user = User.query.filter_by(email == data['email'])`, what is `user.device.token` set to? If that's `None`, then that's why you see that reflected in the response.

Comment: @ken: there are more problems with the code in your question here that make it harder for me to help you. Your `Device` model in your question doesn't have a `id` field, it only has `user_device_id` as the primary key.

Comment: opps...my bad.let me edit my question again..wait a minute

Comment: sir,I edited my question.. the `id` in `device` class is the `foreignKey` from `User` object.

Comment: can you take a look again for my `User` and `Device` class? now is exactly the same with my code now..

Comment: @ken: ah, I see. Your `User.device` attribute is a *list*, because you created a [one-to-many relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many). I'll be back in a bit to update my answer here, but you could try `attribute='device.0.token'` here to get just the single, first element.

Comment: @ken: the correct solution is to use a [One to One mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one), so `device = db.relationship('Device', backref='user', uselist=False)`

Comment: ok bro..I try for my own 1st..If possible please edit your answer as well..is really really appreciate..cause I total beginner on this..hahaha